# Return values in column based on sum in other column

Tags: sql

I have the following table and want to return values in the id column where the sum of the values in the paid column are equal to or above 3.

```
id         paid     
30          1    
20          0   
30          1    
40          1  
30          0     
30          1    
20          0
```

So for the above table (orders), the query should return 30 but not 20 or 40. I feel like this should be a simple query and have tried the following, which didn't work:

```
SELECT id FROM orders
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(status >= 3)
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: try `HAVING SUM(paid) >= 3`

Comment: "didn't work" - why not> what happened? why was that wrong? "`status`" - what is that? it's not shown in your schema.

Comment: How is status related to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query. You have to compare the complete sum not the value before you build the sum.

`SELECT id FROM orders GROUP by id HAVING SUM(paid) >= 3`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given your exact database schema (Below): 
[image]

Your filter of wanting 3 would not yield any results, as no ID has 3 instances of "paid"
However, the following SQL code works and does yield results:

```
SELECT orders.myID
FROM orders
GROUP BY myID
HAVING SUM(paid >= 1)
```

[image]

All you would need to do is change the `HAVING SUM(paid >= 1)` to include whichever number threshold for the instances of "paid"

You did not give us a "status" field in your schema, but given what you were looking for, the mentioned should work.

You might include referencing your database (mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Access, etc.), your entire schema, example data, and what you are trying to accomplish, as well as any error messages your code is currently going so that we can give you the best possible answers.

However, this method should work for you :) Please let me know if it doesn't.